# Chrome tracks 2 history entries even when submitting a PRG-based form

Tags: php, forms, node.js, google-chrome, browser-history

Chrome tracks TWO history entries - instead of only ONE - when submitting a form that implements "Post + Same Page Redirect + Get" method.

### The steps that demonstrate this strange behaviour.

1 - I browse to the form page Naked form page : demo.html.
Naked form page:
[image: Naked form page (demo.html)]

2 - I fill the form.
Filled form:

[image: Filled form (demo.html)]

3 - I submit the form.
Submited -thus empty - form (at demo.html, as redirected from my PRG-based redirect-to-same-page.php):

[image]

4 - I click on the browser's "back" button once.

#### Chrome jumps back to the filled form (step)

[image]

5 - I need to click on the browser's "back" button another time to reach the page I was browsing before I went to that form page (say my browser's "google" default page):
[image]

This happens with Chrome (version 25.0.1364.172) and Safari (6.0.2)

### What I'm expecting

I'm expecting to have a single browser's "back" click to reach the page before the form.
This is actually how Firefox (19.0.2) Opera (12.11), and IE (from version 6 to latest 10) behave.

### My source code

demo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="redirect-to-same-page.php" method="post">
    Type something and submit: <input type="text" name="something" /> <!-- optional: autocomplete="off" -->
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

redirect-to-same-page.php

```
<?php
header('Location: demo.html', true, 302); // not any of true/false 302/303 combinations are working
// not working either: header("Refresh: 0; demo.html");
exit;
?>
```

### What Chrome's web inspector reveals...

1 Before submission :
[image]

2 After submission :
[image]

### My questions

I read similar questions and potential answers but none of them solved my problem.

Is this behaviour a Chrome/Safari issue or a feature* ? (* in the case submission fails it retains a full backup of your filled form)

Is there a correct or more defensive code for node.js or php to avoid this behaviour ?

Thanks for your help